# Turkish character in QPushButton text

Tags: qt, locale, qt4.8, qpushbutton

I am using Qt 4.8.6 with vs2010.

I create a form and inserted QPushbutton with text "İleri".

It is Ok when program starts. After I change text in code:

```
ui.btSenaryoIleri->setText("İleri");
```

it becomes Yleri.

Should I change some settings in code?

Answer (score 3):

You should use `QObject::tr` + English text (not Turkish) in your source files, and provide corresponding translation.

See [how to do it](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/i18n-source-translation.html) and read about [internationalization](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/internationalization.html) in Qt.

Comment: Personally, I think this makes development overly complex when he doesn't want to make a multilingual application.

Comment: @JeffreyvandeGlind, there are no guarantee from C++ compilers, that they should support all text encodings and do a compilation depending on current system locale. So it is correct. And it is a good practice to split resources and code. Texts on controls are resources.

Comment: But why designer supports Turkish and code not?

There must be something else I think.

Comment: @MuzafferKaraman if you don't trust to an official documentation then be free to find your own solutions :)

Comment: a workaround getting Turkish text in constructor to a Qstring and set it after.

ileri = ui.btSenaryoIleri->text();
...
ui.btSenaryoIleri->setText(ileri);

Comment: @MuzafferKaraman you may open a generated ui_*.h file and see, how it's doing by moc.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is encoding of source code incompatible with encoding used to covert c-strings to `QString`. Probably you need UTF-8 -> UTF-16 but conversion is done from other encoding system (this is fetch from current locale).

Best solution is use tr function (as described in other answer).
As alternative ensure that conversion is done from proper encoding:

```
ui.btSenaryoIleri->setText(QString::fromUtf8("İleri"));
```

Make sure that your source code is UTF-8 encoded.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

```
ui.btSenaryoIleri->setText(QString::fromLocal8Bit("İleri"));
```

But it will only work with Turkish OS.

Comment: You may configure locale of "Turkish OS" to be Russian, and your code will not work too. It is a bad practice to write a code that will works only on developers PC. But if you are doing a project to yourself and don't care about product quality, then it is OK.

Comment: This will only works on Turkish PC. I got what you mean. But don't you think qt's tr function and all translate stuff is hard way to just change a labels text

Comment: if you ensure that your source code is utf8 encoded and use `QString::fromUtf8` it will work on any PC with different locale set. Still best approach is to use english strings and provide translation.

Comment: Surprisingly, `fromUtf8` works fine for `QLabel`, but for `QPushButton`, `fromLocal8Bit` should be used....